# CSS Animation in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, css-animations

The following code will display a CSS animated 'pulsing' circle.

In works in all browsers but not in Internet explorer.

How can I make it work in Internet Explorer?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/danest/pen/GxfqB/

```
#container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background: #45453f;
}

.pulse {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #f7f14c;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #716f42;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
}

.dot {
  border: 10px solid #fff601;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  -moz-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  animation: pulse 3s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: -25px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
 0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
 25% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
   opacity: 0.1;
 }
 50% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
 }
 75% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
 }
 100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes "pulse" {
 0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
 25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
 }
 50% {
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
 }
 75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.5;
 }
 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
}
```

Comment: You're only specifying `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes. Add an `-ms-` prefixed version and a non-prefixed version too.

Comment: Also mention the IE version that you are using. If your intention is to support modern browsers, you can remove the prefixes and use the standard CSS properties as well.

Comment: remove your prefixed in your keyframes, just use it only in your calling animation example, -webkit-animation: pulse; -moz-animation: pulse; -ms-animation: pulse; -o-animation: pulse; animation: pulse your keyframes should look like this @keyframes pulse { //styles here } it will help also to lessen your codes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this site can help you : http://caniuse.com/
there is a page dedicate for complex method of animating certain properties of an element : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Answer (score 0):

With the help of previous answers I solved this (Thank you)

I needed to add the 'modern' keyframes without prefix. This works in IE 10

```
@keyframes pulse {
 0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
 25% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0.1;
 }
 50% {
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
 }
 75% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.7;
 }
 100% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity: 0.0;
 }
}
```